# How to limit memory consumption of individual child processes of a (systemd) service?

Tags: systemd, memory, cgroups

I am working on an application that processes files in background jobs. The jobs are picked up by a worker process, which spawns a command for each job. The worker supervisor process is running in a systemd unit.

Some files cause the executed command to consume an excessive amount of memory, starving the rest of the system. Therefore, I would like to limit the amount of memory that each spawned process is allowed to consume. Terminating individual processing jobs is acceptable.

First I tried working with `ulimit`, but this does not seem to work well. My understanding is that the "modern" approach is to use cgroups (see e.g [here](https://superuser.com/a/1551941/117404)). And indeed, if I run

```
systemd-run --user --scope -p MemoryHigh=200M -p MemoryMax=250M MemorySwapMax=0M /path/to/program
```

the program slows down and is finally terminated if the input file causes it to allocate more memory. Great!

I could add these memory limits to the systemd unit file of the supervisor process, however that would terminate all jobs and the supervisor if one single job consumes too much RAM.

I then altered the application code to spawn new processes with a `systemd-run` "wrapper" like above. However, this fails with

> Failed to connect to bus: No medium found

It looks like I can't use `systemd-run --user` in the context of the service, which runs as an unprivileged system user in a systemd service, because it seems it needs an active user session. Using `systemd-run --system` on the other hand fails with

> Failed to start transient scope unit: Interactive authentication required.

and I'd rather avoid running the service as root.

So, how can I limit the memory consumption of individual child processes that my service spawns?
Currently I'm running systemd 251 on Arch, but it would be great if this would also work on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04.